# Is there ever a valid reason to not return *this from copy assignment operator?

Tags: c++, copy-assignment

Let `foo` be a struct or class with a copy assignment operator:

```
struct foo {
    foo &operator=(const foo &);  // or with some other return type?
};
```

Is there *ever* a sensible reason to return anything other than `*this` from the `operator=()`? Using it for something unrelated to assignment doesn't qualify as sensible.

Comment: When you return `this*`, you're making it possible for the assignment operator to be chained like `i = j = k = ...`. You can return other stuff, but how useful that is would be based on your definitions and how you want your classes to be used

Comment: Expression templates.

Comment: @AlanStokes It would be nice if you elaborated on that, you know.

Comment: interesting question, but why are you asking? Is it really a [practical, detailed question](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)? Then try to show it.

Comment: note: the answers to the duplicate explore various scenarios where `*this` is not returned

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The example from the standard is [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator%3D). It returns the assigned value. If it returned reference, then reading through it might yield different result.

Comment: Do you know other examples?

Comment: @Wolf: Boost::Phoenix is a library to create lazy expressions. So the `operator=()` there would return some object that you could call `operator()()` on to actually perform the assignment.

Comment: @BillLynch this seems to be what Alan Stokes mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent assignment chaining.

Sometimes its nice to prevent expressions like this:

```
x = y = z = a = b = c = d = foo{15};
```

So you make the assignment operator return void.

```
struct foo {
    void operator=(const foo &);
};
```

For some types chaining does not make sense. But you have to look at that on a case be case basis.